# Calculate time between a special occurrence and the two next consecutive date

Tags: r, dataframe

Below I have data-frame, and want to find first the position of a special occurrence and calculate time difference between this special occurrence (Alert) and two next consecutive item,

```
id     date         type
2      2015-03-01   a
3      2015-12-12   b
2      2015-01-05   Alert
2      2015-01-15   c
2      2015-01-01   d
2      2015-12-02   a
3      2015-12-02   Alert
3      2015-12-02   a
4      2015-12-02   b
3      2015-12-12   a
...
```

and below dataframe is expected:

```
id     days_diffrence_1     days_difference_2
2      10                   55
3      0                    10
4      nan                  nan
...
```

i have a try but it doesn't works well,

```
  table <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(days_diffrence_1 = as.numeric(date[2] - date[1]),
            days_difference_2 = as.numeric(date[3] - date[1]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`,  `group_by` `id`, `arrange` them by `date`, get indices of special occurrence ("Alert") if present and subtract `date` from that index with that of next two indices. In case, there is no occurence of "Alert" we return `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   arrange(date) %>%
   summarise(inds = if (any(type == "Alert")) which.max(type == "Alert") else NA,
        days_diffrence_1 = as.numeric(date[inds+1] - date[inds]), 
        days_diffrence_2 = as.numeric(date[inds+2] - date[inds])) %>%
   select(-inds)


#     id days_diffrence_1 days_diffrence_2
#  <int>            <dbl>            <dbl>
#1     2               10               55
#2     3                0               10
#3     4               NA               NA
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak, it shows this error , Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots): Column `inds` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2

Comment: @AHAD looks like you have multiple "Alert" for some `ID`s. What would you like to do in such cases ? which "Alert" index do you want to select? Try with `which.max` instead of `which` if you need to consider the first occurrence.

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah

Answer (score 0):

Another tidyverse/dplyr approach

**sample data**

```
df <- read.table(text="id     date         type
2      2015-03-01   a
3      2015-12-12   b
2      2015-01-05   Alert
2      2015-01-15   c
2      2015-01-01   d
2      2015-12-02   a
3      2015-12-02   Alert
3      2015-12-02   a
4      2015-12-02   b
3      2015-12-12   a", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactor = FALSE)
```

**code**

```
library( tidyverse )

df %>% 
  #set date as Date-class
  mutate( date = as.Date( date ) ) %>%
  arrange( date ) %>%
  group_by( id ) %>%
  #calculate days to next event 
  mutate( days_diffrence_1 = ifelse( type == "Alert", lead( date, n = 1L, order_by = id ) - date, NA ),
          days_diffrence_2 = ifelse( type == "Alert", lead( date, n = 2L, order_by = id ) - date, NA ) ) %>%
  filter( !is.na( days_diffrence_1 ) )
```

**result**

```
#      id date       type  days_diffrence_1 days_diffrence_2
#   <int> <date>     <chr>            <dbl>            <dbl>
# 1     2 2015-01-05 Alert               10               55
# 2     3 2015-12-02 Alert                0               10
```

Comment: Based on expected output I think OP doesn't want to miss `ID`s which has no "Alert". They want to return `NA` for those `ID`s.

Comment: @RonakShah looks like you are right... but that's strange since that could also indicate that an `Alert` has occured, but no new event for that `id` has occured after the Alert. Since id's without alerts would get mixed up with id`s with alerts (but without following events),  this could lead to misinterpretation of the results